# SQL injection protection action

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm using PHP to connect to my db with mysqli. The query is made in Java code and send to my PHP script with JSON.

I have one query which is dynamic and made in my code so I can't use prepared statement.

For example I have in one time: `SELECT x FROM y WHERE z = ? AND o =?`. And in other time: `SELECT x FROM y WHERE z = ? AND o =? and k = ? and j =?`

It's by the user choice and I cant know what query will be.

My problem is that I'm exposed to SQL injection.

I thought about one step to protect my db from SQL injection and I want your opinion if it's a good idea or there is a better one. I thought about sending secret key to my PHP script and only if the key is good the SQL action will be.

For example:

```
if($key == "2fdgfg1sdjsdgj2JDSJDFSG2394KSDJG")
{
 // do SQL
}
```

This is what I use in my code. The user can select which car types he want to see from my DB.

In the Android application he have dialog in which he can select which car he want. Then I use this code in my java code:

```
                        int length = usersChecked.length;
                        String sqlQuery = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                            if (usersChecked[i]) {
                                if (sqlQuery.equals(""))
                                    sqlQuery = " = " + list[i];
                                else
                                    sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " OR user = "
                                            + list[i];
                            }
                        }

                        favoritesQuery = "SELECT car, year, gas_type FROM cars_names WHERE user "
                                + sqlQuery
                                + " ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ? , ?";
```

Comment: how does user makes the query and how he selects an option?

Comment: Why do you think Java can not connect to a database directly? I think somebody should give you the "Useless use of PHP" award.

Comment: By the way, this "protection" of yours makes no sense. How such a key supposed to be used at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The query is made in java code and send to my php script with JSON.

## This is what you're doing wrong.

- The query shouldn't be of user choice
- The query shouldn't be made in java (or rather javascript it is) code
- The query shouldn't be sent with JSON

## The query have to be hardcoded in PHP script.

At least you can create your query dynamically, based on the user's choice:

```
$sql = "SELECT x FROM y WHERE z = ?";
if (isset($json['o']))
{
    $sql .= " AND o =?";
    $values[] = $json['o']
}
// and so on
```

Comment: From where is $_GET['o'] get from?

Comment: From your javascript. You have to move this query building code from JS to PHP

Comment: But i think that hackers still can inject you code.

If they put for JSON o values to be "DROP table ....." they can still inject. or im wrong?

Comment: This is what **parameters** (? marks) are for. Their only purpose is to make this `"DROP table ....."` as harmless a chicken

Comment: as long as you have `OR user = ` code in PHP, **it cannot be altered by anyone**. While having this part coded in JS, it is obviously can be injected into.